# How to setup development environment for Google Appengine Java Managed VM using Eclipse and Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, google-managed-vm

I'm using Eclipse Luna and have a project using Appengine java managed VM using maven. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/maven

How to setup eclipse for best productivity.

I currently run `mvn gcloud:run` on command line and attach "Remote Java Application" Debug configuration.

I have this in my pom to enable "remote debug"

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gcloud.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <jvm_flag>
            <param>-Xdebug</param>
            <param>-Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n</param>
        </jvm_flag>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Debug and breakpoints work but I have a problem with automatic reload.

- Code rebuild and reload work but it disconnects debug every time I save a .java file.
- static file (.html) rebuild/republish does not work. I have to manual run mvn install on every change.

So the question is: What are the best practices for this.

Answer (score 0):

- Install the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download) (GPE)
- Install [jRebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/eclipse/) - note this is a commercial product, but there are free versions for some types of usage
- configure project as appengine project
- add jRebel nature
- [Debug within eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0%23app-engine-only-applications)

This should hot load Java, jsps, tags and web resources.